# How to import from same level __init__.py?

Tags: python, import, package, this, init

I have this package structure:

```
project/
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── App.py
```

This is the **__init__** file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
```

And the **App.py** file:

```
from . import app, api
from flask_restful import Resource


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

At the first line of App.py i'm trying to import app and api from the the current package but when i run the app with

```
python src/App.py
```

it prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/App.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src import app, api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

How can i resolve the problem without changing the idea of the structure i want. I know i could make another subdirectory/subpackage instead and move there the **init**.py then use `from subpackage import app, api` and it would work. But i don't want that, i want to keep the structure.

Also when i say:

```
from __init__ import app, api
```

it works but the code is ugly at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `project` path to `PYTHONPATH`, then python can find `src` package.

Please note, when you run `src/App.py`, python will try to find modules from the same level directory of `App.py` instead of current working directory. And `from . import app, api` will not work, because at that time, `src/App.py` actually is `__main__`, python cannot find its relative package.